# JavaScript dynamically change div (footer) position - what is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, css, positioning

I'm building a Wordpress theme and I have a problem with footer position. Index page is fine, I defined in style.css margin-top of "footer", witch holds bckimage to 900px and margin-top of "foot_sadrzaj" to 918px, because "foot_sadrzaj" holds text and images. Here's link: http://casabianca.ba/test/

Well, if I go to page, content of the page is in  or, when displaying posts, in . I wrote some JS code to change position of a footer and foot_sadrzaj depending on position and height of sadrzaj or sadrzaj_single, elements containing content, but it doesn't work (like here: http://casabianca.ba/test/novosti/).... Can you help me figure out why?

Here,s the code:

```
var div = getElementById('sadrzaj');
var div2 = getElementById('sadrzaj_single');


if (div) {
    var z = div.style.offsetTop+div.style.offsetHeight;
    getElementById('footer').setAttribute(
            "style", "marginTop:" + z.toString() + "px");
    getElementById('foot_sadrzaj').setAttribute(
            "style", "marginTop:" + (z+18).toString() + "px");
}
else if (div2) {
    var z = div2.style.offsetTop+div2.style.offsetHeight;
    getElementById('footer').setAttribute(
            "style", "marginTop:" + z.toString() + "px");
    getElementById('foot_sadrzaj').setAttribute(
            "style", "marginTop:" + (z+18).toString() + "px");
}
```

Please, all I know is some JS and zero JQuery so answering something like "Try Jquery, I think that..." will not be helpfull at all....

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using absolute positioning on every element instead of floats?

Comment: just a note, you don't need the .toString() here, it'll cast it to a string automatically.

Comment: I converted existing static HTML page to Wordpress theme, so we can say that I "inherited" absolute positioning and now I just want to patch it up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few fixes in your code

```
window.onload = function ()
    {
        var div=document.getElementById('sadrzaj');
        var div2=document.getElementById('sadrzaj_single');

        if(div) {
            var z=div.offsetTop+div.offsetHeight;
            var footer = document.getElementById('footer');
            footer.setAttribute("style","margin-top:" + z.toString() + "px");

            var foot_sadrzaj = document.getElementById('foot_sadrzaj');
            foot_sadrzaj.setAttribute("style","margin-top:" + (z+18) + "px");
        }
        else if (div2) {
            var z=div2offsetTop+div2.offsetHeight;
            document.getElementById('footer').setAttribute("style","margin-top:" + z + "px");
            document.getElementById('foot_sadrzaj').setAttribute("style","margin-top:" + (z+18) + "px");
        }
    }
```

1. you should use `window.onload`, to run your script only after the document is ready
2. you dont need `style` in `div.style.offsetTop+div.style.offsetHeight`.
3. you write `margin-top` in the `.setAttribute` function, and not `marginTop`.
4. you dont have to add `toString()`, JS knows how to handle this
5. this line `document.getElementById('footer').setAttribute("style","margin-top:" + z + "px");` is disabling the inline `background-image` attribute you wrote there, I assume you can handle this yourself from here

Comment: 5. I did by putting it in style.css
Thnx a lot for the inputs, thanks to you, I managed to make it work. I had to reorganize a bit my HTML and make few changes in CSS, but basically, you solved the problem :)
Now code looks like this:

Comment: window.onload = function () {
        var div=document.getElementById('sadrzaj');
        if(div) {
            var z=div.offsetTop+div.offsetHeight;
     var z2=div.offsetTop+div.offsetHeight+18;

            var footer = document.getElementById('footer');
            footer.setAttribute("style","margin-top:" + z.toString() + "px");

            var foot_sadrzaj = document.getElementById('foot_sadrzaj');
            foot_sadrzaj.setAttribute("style","margin-top:" + z2 + "px");
        }
    }</code>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `margin-top` use `"bottom : 0"` for aligning things to the bottom of your container div. Then stop using the Javascript to define position and instead just use CSS.

it might even be fun to set `"z-index:100000"` and `"position:fixed"`

Comment: I tried "bottom: 0" and all I get was footer who was at the bottom of the window, not the page... Don't know why, honestly, I don't have the time to play around with it.
"position: fixed" helped me even less... I tried it all before I wrote the code above ;)

Comment: One more thing: My footer is outside of wrapper div because wrapper is in the middle of the page, width:1000px, but footer div must be width:100%, at the bottom and spread trough the whole page ;)

Answer (score 0):

Even tough code worked, I missed one angle: what if content is smaller than browser window. or there is no content yet? Then my footer is hanging somewhere in the middle, not at the bottom. Here is the solution, thanks to @Mitz and [James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/)

Final solution:

```
function getDocHeight() {
var D = document;
return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}

window.onload = function (){
    var div=document.getElementById('sadrzaj');
    if(div) {
        var z=div.offsetTop+div.offsetHeight;
    var z2=div.offsetTop+div.offsetHeight+18;
    var windowHeight= getDocHeight();
if(z>windowHeight) {
        var footer = document.getElementById('footer');
        footer.setAttribute("style","margin-top:" + z + "px");

        var foot_sadrzaj = document.getElementById('foot_sadrzaj');
        foot_sadrzaj.setAttribute("style","margin-top:" + z2 + "px");
}
else {
    var footer = document.getElementById('footer');
        footer.setAttribute("style","margin-top:" + windowHeight + "px");

        var foot_sadrzaj = document.getElementById('foot_sadrzaj');
        foot_sadrzaj.setAttribute("style","margin-top:" + (windowHeight+18) + "px");
    }
}
```